# Unresolved reference errors in Activities

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I am using android studio 2022-3-19 (Giraffe). And the errors occur in only activities, not in fragments, about registerForActivityResult(), viewModels() and some others.
[image]
These errors occur after I upgrade jdk version from 11 to 18 and gradle version from 7.5 to 8.0. And the strange thing is that the project can build without any issue.
How can I fix this issue.

build.gradle file.

```
    plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'com.google.firebase.appdistribution'
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.xxxxxxx'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxxxxxx"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 43
        versionName "1.43"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        def buildTime = new Date()
        buildConfigField "String", "BUILD_TIME", "\"${buildTime.format('yyyyMMddHHmmss')}\""

        externalNativeBuild {
            externalNativeBuild {
                cmake {
                    cppFlags "-std=c++11 -frtti -fexceptions"

                    abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
                    
                    arguments "-DANDROID_ARM_NEON=TRUE"
                    arguments "-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang"
                }
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_18
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_18
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_18
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

kapt {
    correctErrorTypes true
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-csv:2.12.5'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.12.5'

    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.2.2')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx'

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.5.5'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0-alpha02'

    implementation 'com.google.android.flexbox:flexbox:3.0.0'

    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.44"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.6.0'
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.44"

    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-core:1.2.1"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.2.1"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.2.1"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-video:1.2.1"

    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:1.2.1"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-extensions:1.2.1"

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-face-detection:17.1.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

    implementation "com.tbuonomo:dotsindicator:4.3"
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.15.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10.1'

    implementation 'lib.kashif:folderpicker:2.4'
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to invalidate cache and restart?

Comment: @AbdullahJaved Yes, I already tried.